# Optimal mullps/addps instructions order for 3 SSE units for Intel Core 2 Duo

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86, intel, sse

It's known that Intel Core 2 Duo has 3 SSE units. These 3 units allows 3 SSE instructions to be run paralelly **(1)**, for example:

```
rA0 = mullps(rB0, rC0);   \
rA1 = mullps(rB1, rC1);    > All 3 take 1 cycle to be scheduled (* - see Remarks).
rA2 = mullps(rB2, rC2);   /
```

It's known also, that each SSE unit consists of 2 modules: one for addition (substraction), and one for multiplication (division). The latter allows to run mullps-addps instruction sequences parallelly **(2)**, for example:

```
rA0 = mullps(rB0, rC0); \
                         > All 2 take 1 cycle to be scheduled for 1 SSE module.
rA1 = addps(rB1, rC1);  /
```

Question is the followig: how much cycles each of the following 2 code snippets take to be scheduled?

Code listing A:

```
rA0 = mullps(rB0, rC0);  \ 
rA1 = mullps(rB1, rC1);   |  
rA2 = mullps(rB2, rC2);   \ Do all 6 execute in one step? (See paragraph (2))
rA3 = addps(rB3, rC3);    /
rA4 = addps(rB4, rC4);    | 
rA5 = addps(rB5, rC5);   /
```

Code listing B:

```
rA0 = mullps(rB0, rC0);  \ 
rA1 = addps(rB1, rC1);    |  
rA2 = mullps(rB2, rC2);    \ Do all 6 execute in one step?  (See paragraph (1))
rA3 = addps(rB3, rC3);     /
rA4 = mullps(rB4, rC4);   | 
rA5 = addps(rB5, rC5);   /
```

Which way of instruction ordering should I prefer, A or B?

More specifically:

1. Is it possible to distribute 3 mulps to 3 SSE multiplication units (1), and at the same time (2) to distribute addps to their respective SSE addition units, resulting in total 6 instructions per schedule cycle?
2. If I run N mullps first, and N addps then - which N is optimal?

**Remarks**

- by 'scheduled' I mean throughput rate.

Comment: Woah woah... You're completely off here. A Core 2 processor does have 3 SSE units. But they do different things. 1 for addition/subtraction. 1 for multiplication, and 1 for shuffling. In both examples, you will never get a throughput of more than 3 cycles. And you're gonna want to read a bit about [OOE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution). So the order shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: Even if you did have a unit capable of both operations, you'd still have a single port leading to it

Comment: Huh... thanks for clarification. Will be reading the article.

Comment: The order will only matter on the Intel Atom which does not have OOE.

Answer (score 0):

See [Agner Fog's](http://agner.org/optimize/) instruction tables for which instructions can run on which execution units.  And/or use Intel's code analyzer (IACA) to find throughput bottlenecks (dependency chains or port contention).

As the commenters say, not all the execution ports can handle FP MUL.  They can all handle vector-int logicals (AND/OR/XOR), but only one or two ports have a vector shuffle unit, or a vector shift unit, etc. etc.